# How to display a sum of values in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a time tracking project in React. What I'm trying to do is the following:

- in each project I have a form to add activities and time;
- I want to get the amount of time to be added and displayed at the end like a total - so if I have two activities, one with 2 hours, another with 3, "Total" should display the sum - 5 hours.

Some code:

- Times component (contains the list of activities):

```
const Times = ({ times, onDelete }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {times.length > 0 ? <p className="time-title">Time</p> : <p className="no-time-msg">Time: nothing here yet</p>}
            {times.map((time, index) => (<Time key={index} time={time} onDelete={onDelete}/>))}
            <TimeTotal />
       </div>
    )
}
```

- Time component (contains activity, date and amount of time):

```
const Time = ({ time, onDelete }) => {
    return (
        <div className="hours-table">
            <h3>Activity: {time.activity}</h3>
            <h4>Date: {time.date}</h4>
            <TimeAmount time={time} />
            <FaTrash className="time-delete-icon" onClick={() => onDelete(time.id)}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

- TimeAmount component (contains the amount of time):

```
const TimeAmount = ({ time }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p value={time.time}>Time: {time.time} hour(s)</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

- TimeTotal component (should display the sum of the amounts of time):

```
const TimeTotal = ({ time }) => {

    const context = useContext(TimeContext)
    console.log(context)
    return <div className="time-total">Total: {context.times.length}</div>

}
```

- In `TimeTotal`, I've used context, but it displays the number of activities, not the total amount of time, like I want.

Comment: Could you show us what `console.log(context)` prints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`context.times` is an array containing activities, right? Well, in javascript, `.length` of an array represents the length of the array itself, so it represents how many activities you have. Javascript has no way to know what you're trying to sum or achieve.

You need to sum the durations yourself by iterating the array of activities, so you need to have:

```
const TimeTotal = ({ time }) => {
    const context = useContext(TimeContext);
    let totalDuration = 0;

    context.times.forEach((entry) => {
        totalDuration += entry.time;
    });

    return <div className="time-total">Total: {totalDuration}</div>
}
```

A shorter version would be:

```
const context = useContext(TimeContext);
const totalDuration = context.times.reduce((total, entry) => entry.time + total, 0)

const TimeTotal = ({ time }) => {
    const context = useContext(TimeContext)l
    const totalDuration = context.times.reduce((total, entry) => entry.time + total, 0);

    return <div className="time-total">Total: {totalDuration}</div>
}
```

You can read more about reduce [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: And in what component should I add this ? And where should ```totalDuration``` be displayed ?

Comment: @George In `TimeTotal`, right? I updated my answer to reflect these changes.

Comment: I think it works, but instead of displaying the sum of the numbers, it just adds up to a big number - if I add 2 hours, it says 20, if I add 1 hour, it says 120 and so on - the newest number gets added to the front.

Comment: @George that's because your duration gets saved as a string, not as a number. If you "add" strings, you actually just concatenate values. You can fix this by having `parseInt(entry.time) + total` where the total is calculated or by making sure that the component that returns the time returns a number instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce()` method of Array, something like

```
const timesSum = context.times.reduce((acc, {time}) => {
  return acc + time
}, 0)
```

Take into account that I assumed `time` as numeric type. In real life you may need to cast time to number on manipulate it's value the way you need. Maybe you'll have to format `timesSum`.

Finally you'll have something like:

```
const TimeTotal = ({ time }) => {

    const context = useContext(TimeContext)
    console.log(context)
    
    const timesSum = context.times.reduce((acc, {time}) => {
      return acc + time
    }, 0);


    return <div className="time-total">Total: {timesSum}</div>

}
```

Comment: I get the same bug here - if I add 2 hours it says 02, and then, if I add 1 hour, it says 021 and so on.

Comment: What's in `context.times` array?

Comment: I think the data from the activities is stored in there.

Comment: I need to see objects structure to fix the problem.

Comment: The object in the console log ?

Comment: At least console.log().

Comment: Well, in the console log, there is an Object with: setTimes, times: []. In the times array, there is the data for each activity: activity name and date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235344/discussion-between-lazy-lizard-and-george).